# put comma in numbers on json array using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want to put comma's in numbers
The output is this which is encoded in json array

```
[{"total2":"7619627.0000"}]
```

I want to change the number in this format

```
[{"total2":"7,619,627"}]
```

heres the php code

```
$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(NettoPrice) AS total2 FROM Sales WHERE OrderType = 8";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

// output data of each row
while($row[] = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

   $json = json_encode($row);


}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This is an invalid syntax for numbers according to [json official site](http://json.org/)

Comment: To format a number use `number_format`.

Comment: according to this [link](https://jsonlint.com) it is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MYSQL 5.5:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(NettoPrice),0) AS total2;
```

[**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0994a7/2)

With PHP

```
number_format('7619627.0000',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use number_format();

```
$row[count($row)-1]['total2'] = number_format($row[count($row)-1]['total2']);
$json = json_encode($row);
```